# Increase the seekbar music playback display time update

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, seekbar

Members predecessors.
Recently learning to make simple applications.
Want to ask how to read music on the web.
How to increase the seekbar display progress?
And then increase the display of the current playing time and the total time.

My code:

```
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;

import static tw.edu.ctust.f10308023.mismediaplayer.R.id.btnBackward;
import static tw.edu.ctust.f10308023.mismediaplayer.R.id.btnPlay;

public class Player_one extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ImageButton ib1, ib2, ib3;
    ImageView iv;
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private Handler myHandler = new Handler();
    private int forwardTime = 5000;
    private int backwardTime = 5000;
    private double startTime = 0;
    private double finalTime = 0;
    private TextView tx1, tx2, tx3;

    private int seekForwardTime = 5000; // 5000 milliseconds
    private int seekBackwardTime = 5000; // 5000 milliseconds

    String AudioURL = "http://k003.kiwi6.com/hotlink/hyzvh0ugcl/cytussaika.mp3";

    MediaPlayer mediaplayer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player_one);

        iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        ib1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(btnPlay);//播放
        ib2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(btnBackward);//倒轉
        ib3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnForward);//快轉
        tx1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songCurrentDurationLabel);
        tx2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songTotalDurationLabel);
        tx3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songTitle);
        tx3.setText("Cytus-saika");
        View v = findViewById(R.id.player_footer_bg);
        v.getBackground().setAlpha(75);//0~255透明度值

        mediaplayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaplayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);


        ib1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                if (mediaplayer.isPlaying()) {
                    mediaplayer.pause();
                    ib1.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
                } else {
                    mediaplayer.start();
                    ib1.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
                }

                try {

                    mediaplayer.setDataSource(AudioURL);
                    mediaplayer.prepare();

                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SecurityException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        });
                ib2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // get current song position
                int currentPosition =mediaplayer.getCurrentPosition();
                // check if seekBackward time is greater than 0 sec
                if(currentPosition - seekBackwardTime >= 0){
                    // forward song
                    mediaplayer.seekTo(currentPosition - seekBackwardTime);
                }else{
                    // backward to starting position
                    mediaplayer.seekTo(0);
                }

            }
        });
                ib3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

            {
                @Override
                public void onClick (View arg0){
                // get current song position
                int currentPosition = mediaplayer.getCurrentPosition();
                // check if seekForward time is lesser than song duration
                if (currentPosition + seekForwardTime <= mediaplayer.getDuration()) {
                    // forward song
                    mediaplayer.seekTo(currentPosition + seekForwardTime);
                } else {
                    // forward to end position
                    mediaplayer.seekTo(mediaplayer.getDuration());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "無法快轉", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am suggesting you to have a look at [this link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-building-audio-player-tutorial/). It's a very much explained tutorial about how you can update your seekbar and maintain the time accordingly.

Though it's play audio from the local you can always pass the url of the audio file to the **MusicPlayer** class.

Hope this works for you!